# How to play video fullscreen using embed tag?

Tags: html, embed

I am playing video in html using embed tag. How to play the video in full screen instead of configuring a particular value for width and height? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try look here:

http://soundscreen.com/qt_webmasters/fullscreen.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS44B1892B-1668-4a80-8431-6BA0F1947766.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve that with `<embed>`.

Comment: is it possible with any other tag(that can play mpg file)?

Answer (score 0):

Embed a player that can play videos full-screen (e.g., JWPlayer) and stuff your video to it. Alternatively, if you don't want to rely on Flash use HTML5 video tag and the browser will let the user switch to full screen.